# Child thread seems not to complete if parent completes earlier

Tags: java, multithreading

I created an EventEmitter that passes the events to the listeners in a new thread:

```
public class EventEmitter{

private Map<String,List<EventListener>> listeners = new HashMap<String,List<EventListener>>();
private Executor executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();

protected EventEmitter(Executor executor){
    this.executor = executor;
}

public void publish(Event e) {
    listeners.get(e.getClass().toString()).stream().forEach(listener->{
        executor.execute(()->{listener.beNotifiedOfEvent(e);});
    });
}

public void subscribe(EventListener listener,Class<?> eventClass) {

    assert Arrays.asList(eventClass.getInterfaces()).contains(Event.class);

    List<EventListener> listenersThatListenToIt = listeners.get(eventClass.toString());

    if(listenersThatListenToIt!=null){
        listenersThatListenToIt.add(listener);
    } else {
        listenersThatListenToIt = new ArrayList<EventListener>();
        listenersThatListenToIt.add(listener);
        listeners.put(eventClass.toString(),listenersThatListenToIt);
    }

}
}
```

I also print a message in the listener after two seconds when an event is received:

```
@Component
public class StudentRegisteredEventListener implements EventListener {

@Override
public void beNotifiedOfEvent(Event e) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    StudentRegisteredEvent studentRegisteredEvent = (StudentRegisteredEvent) e;
    System.out.println("Received student registered event! Student's name is: "+studentRegisteredEvent.getRegisteredStudent());
}

}
```

I have the following JUnit test:

```
    @Test
public void test_emitter_notifies_listener() {
    //given
    EventEmitter emitter = new CachedThreadPoolEventEmitter();
    //StudentRegisteredEvent event = new StudentRegisteredEvent();

    EventListener listener = Mockito.mock(StudentRegisteredEventListener.class);

    Student registeredStudent = new Student();
    registeredStudent.setName("studentName");

    //when
    emitter.subscribe(listener,StudentRegisteredEvent.class);
    emitter.publish(new StudentRegisteredEvent(registeredStudent));

    //then

    System.out.println("end of test");
}
```

My problem is that when the parent thread ends before the end of the "beNotifiedOfEvent" call, the line from the listener method is not printed, so I only see "end of test" on the console.

What I'm interested in is: what is the reason for this behaviour, and whether or not this will work outside of the context of a test. I plan to publish the event from a Spring MVC controller. Is this guaranteed to complete after the the parent thread is done with the execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it does not work within the context of a test, you should not take anyone's word for it that it may work outside the context of a test.  Get your test to work correctly first.

If you want your test to complete normally, then you have to wait for all threads that it spawned to end.  Assuming your `Executor` is actually an `ExecutorService`, this is done as follows:

```
executorService.shutdown();
try 
{
    executorService.awaitTermination(Long.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
}
catch (InterruptedException e) 
{
    ...
}
```

While the above code is executing, your task should run to completion, so you should see the message displayed right before your task ends.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the thread terminating but the whole process. [JUnit kills the process when the test finishes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550986/5108418), so **not even non-daemon threads can keep a JUnit testing process alive.** (It is totally straightforward if you think about it, noone wants a test process running after it finished actual testing). [In Java, threads do not have a hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11722898/5108418), there is no such thing as a 'parent' thread. However nearly every application has some kind of 'main' thread. JUnit has its own main thread, runs the tests inside it, and calls `System.exit(0);` at the end.

If you want to test some timed events, you will have to explicitly wait in the test case for the threads. Additionally, I would recommend to use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of `Thread.sleep`-s.