# Junit - test case with thread.sleep doesn't wait for the completion of thread

Tags: java, junit

I have a couple of junit test cases where I am calling a method `doComplexOperation()`  that starts a new thread and prints 0-5 with 100ms sleep in each loop.

When I run each of the test method individually, they all produce different results:

- main method -> prints 0-5
- test1-> print 0 OR doesn't print anything at all
- test2-> prints 0-3
- test3-> prints 0-5

In all these tests the main thread doesn't wait for the thread created in `doComplexOperation` to finish. I am expecting similar output when running the `main()` method or the `@Tests`

**Is there a configuration on JUnit so that I can have all these tests print 0-4?**

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class Tests {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        doComplexOperation();
    }

    @Test
    void test1() {
        doComplexOperation(); //Prints 0 OR doesn't print anything at all 
    }

    @Test
    void test2() {
        doComplexOperation(); //Prints 0 - 3
        sleep(300);
    }

    @Test
    void test3() {
        doComplexOperation(); //Prints 0 - 4
        sleep(1000);
    }

    static void doComplexOperation() {
        new Thread(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + "-" + i);
                sleep(100);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    static void sleep(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What about using `join()` when you want to wait for the thread to finish?

Comment: I could do the following. But doComplexOperation is from a third party library in my real code. I was hoping JUnit might have some config  
``        Thread t = new Thread(() -> {... the code );
        
        t.start();
        t.join();
``

Comment: Does the API `doComplexOperation()` allows you somehow to react/act/wait on the created threads? Please edit your question to include a detailed description of your unit test and third party library, how you use it, what the API is (link to documentation?) and what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also, i think it might be a defect with JUnit becase I expect the same result when running    `` doComplexOperation();`` from main method or from a @Test

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550922/why-non-daemon-thread-is-terminating-if-in-junit-test

Comment: thanks for the pointer, it looks it was a feature not a bug :D